# Managing content in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using liferay 6.2 for migrating my existing web application to liferay.I have done below things:
-->created my own theme extending the _styled theme

-->customized the navigation to have fixed sidebar on the left and content area on the right.

-->Added 3 web content display portlets dynamically and added the content into each of them.

I have all the portlets residing on the same page,these are traversed by using navigation bar on the left side. Now I have new requirement to show content depending on the client.

For e.g. I have 3 client's data right now mixed all together across all portlets ,I have requirement to segregate all the content.For e.g. If user logging in work for X client ,he/she should only see the relevant content . If there is some content which is common to all it should be displayed as it is.

There should also be a way to add/remove client at runtime.Is liferay multi-site capability something I can make use of?

How can I go ahead and achieve this? Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here IMHO. I'd recommend working through Liferay's User Guide (http://www.liferay.com/documentation). Yes, Liferay is capable of doing what you want, and there are several ways to achieve this goal. Which way to go depends on many different issues - like: How many clients/users do you expect? How are the access permissions typically maintained? How fine-grained permissions do you need etc. . Also note that Liferay is offering trainings - "Liferay Fundamentals" seems to be appropriate (https://www.liferay.com/services/training/topics/fundamentals)

Comment: @Olaf Kock Would you be able to give some sort of pointer,Not realy in terms of broad explanation but some feature name liferay provides to categorize the content in some way and display it accordingly?

Comment: It's hard to tell you where to start. Permissions in Liferay are best organized around individual sites. But without knowing your scenario, this might be the worst pointer I can give you. That's why I believe that it's too broad to be answered here: Need more information

Comment: @Olaf Kock:Here is more info about the scenario.I have only single page with set of portlets each holding different content.For e.g. I have 3 contents ,c1 ,c2 ,c3.I need to show only c1 and c3 to client 1 , only c1 and c2 to client2.For permissions,there would be a user group for each client and users working for that client would be added to respective user group.
I am thinking to tag the content in some wayi.ec1 should be tagged with client1 & client2,c2 should be tagged with client 2 and so on. At runtime depending on the user group of current logged in user I will display/hide the content.

Comment: I'd rather go for a more futureproof way and distribute the differently targeted content to different pages or different sites. Unless you're limited to 3 customers for all time, the solution you have now strictly won't scale. However, your problem is not suitable for a Q&A site like stackoverflow IMHO, you're rather looking for a full architecture but don't give more than your current quick solution. Sorry. Coming back to my initial suggestion: Read the documentation or get someone on board with Liferay experience. Even Liferay (the company) can help you.